# Cocoa detecting key held down

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, events

In Cocoa there is an overridable function for keyDown and keyUp but no keyHeld? Does it have a function or is there a way to check the keystate as in Win32?

This may be a stupid question but my experience in limited and I come from a Win32 background.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what keyHeld does on win32, but the keyDown event is repeated in Cocoa when the key is held down. The rate and delay before being repeated depend on the user settings (you can get the current values with the `+keyRepeatInterval` and `+keyRepeatDelay` methods on `NSEvent`). You can catch if the event is the first keyDown or a repeated one with the event's `isARepeat` property.

I don't believe there is a way to check the keystates in Cocoa. Perhaps you will have more luck with a lower-level API if you absolutely need it. If you only need it for a couple of keys you can probably get away with setting a flag on keyDown and resetting it on keyUp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer for this. When you get a key down event, create a timer with the time interval that defines "held down" for you, and destroy it if you get a key up event for that same key. If the timer fires, then the key was held down for your specified time.

Something roughly like this:

```
- (void)keyDown: (NSEvent *)event
{
    NSTimer * tim = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kKeyHeldInterval 
                                                     target:self 
                                                   selector:@selector(keyHeld:) 
                                                   userInfo:event 
                                                    repeats:NO];

    NSNumber * keyCodeNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:[event keyCode]];
    [[self dictionaryOfKeyHeldTimers] setObject:tim forKey:keyCodeNum];
}

- (void)keyUp: (NSEvent *)event
{
    NSNumber * keyCodeNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:[event keyCode]];
    NSTimer * tim = [[self dictionaryOfKeyHeldTimers] popObjectForKey:keyCodeNum];

    [tim invalidate];
}

- (void)keyHeld: (NSTimer *)tim
{
    // Key was held, take action.
    NSEvent * event = [tim userInfo];
    NSNumber * keyCodeNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:[event keyCode]];
    [[self dictionaryOfKeyHeldTimers] removeObjectForKey:keyCodeNum];
}
```